# Using Getter Method vs Field Within Same Class

Tags: oop, coding-style, refactoring, standards

This question is to address if there is a performance difference or if there is a general standard between calls to the **Getter method vs referencing the specific field** within the class, while in a separate method. Using Java as an example language...

```
public class Person {
   String firstName = "";
   String lastName = "";

   // Insert Constructor

   public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
   public String getLastName() { return lastName; }

   @Override public String toString() {

      return "First Name: " + getFirstName() + "\nLast Name: " + getLastName());
      // OR
      return "First Name: " + firstName + "\nLast Name: " + lastName);
   }

}
```

It may seem small but I have always wondered if the method call to a getter method, inside the class, is extra work for the machine. Does anybody know if there is an impact of one call vs the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. It depends on the language and if that language runs on an optimizing virtual machine. If you're on a JVM based language, using the standard Oracle JVM, then the function overhead will be optimized away after a few method calls.

That said, if you're going to be doing anything like that with inheritance, then I'd recommend always using the "getter" so that overrides respect the new view of the field a child class might bring.

Comment: The equivalent setters should also be used to set fields to enforce any validation and constraints on parameters

Comment: @dkatzel Good point if you use mutable data structures, for whatever reason.